# Remove Full Access permissions from shared folders with exceptions

Tags: powershell

Basically at my new work we have a shared network area with individual folders for each department. Each folder has multiple sub folders. The problem is the previous manager assigned 'full access' security rights on each folder and subfolder to absolutely everyone, including the 'everyone' group. I'd like to change the 'full access' security permissions for modify, but not for certain security groups like domain admins and certain other security groups.

I have some code in PowerShell that gives me a list of which groups have full access permissions but I need to be able to take that list and change them to modify.

This is what I shamelessly stole and modified from someone else.

```
$path = "\\srv-shared\sharedfolders"
$ExcludeUsers = 'Domain\Domain Admins',
                'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',
                'BUILTIN\Administrator',
                'domain\Administrator'

# Create regex-pattern to match all excluded users
$ExcludeUsersRegex = ($ExcludeUsers | % { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Get-Childitem $path -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_

    Get-Acl -Path $file.FullName |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access |
        Where-Object {
            $_.IdentityReference -notmatch $ExcludeUsersRegex -and
            $_.AccessControlType -eq "Allow" -and
            $_.FileSystemRights -eq "FullControl"
        } | ForEach-Object {
            #Foreach ACL
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                Path = $file.FullName
                ACL  = $_.IdentityReference
            }
        }
} | Select-Object -Property Path, ACL | Export-Csv e:\check_acl.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Basically in the #Foreach ACL section i need it to change the full access permission for the group/user its just found and change it to modify instead.

Comment: Best thing to do is [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52716921/edit), post the code you have already, and point out exactly which bit you're stuck on in performing the desired modifications. That way you might receive an answer targeted to solving your particular problem rather than something generic.

Comment: There is icacls.exe for precisely the purpose of comprehensively managing ACLs on the file system. Consider using a tried-and-tested tool instead of rolling your own code.